# How to detect if clicked element was not a child of an element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a nested list in WordPress that when clicked, it will filter products accordingly.

This is how the code looks:

```
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

  <li class="woof_term_224">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent Category 1</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_224">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 1</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <br>

  <li class="woof_term_225">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">>Parent Category 2</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_225">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <br>

  <li class="woof_term_226">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">>Parent Category 3</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_226">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```

•   Parent Category 1
    o Sub Category 1
•   Parent Category 2
    o Sub Category 2
•   Parent Category 3
    o Sub Category 3

I have selector for the clicked  element.

```
j(document).on('click', '.woof_list_radio .woof_radio_label', function(e) {

});
```

If I click Sub Category 1 `<label>` element which is a child of `<li class="woof_term_224">` then I clicked Parent Category 2 `<label>` element, do you know how can I detect if the clicked `<label>` was not a child of `<li class="woof_term_224">` or detect that it was clicked outside its parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the closest with class `woof_term_224` to determine that. You can try the following way by changing the selector to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.woof_list_radio > [class^=woof_term_]', function(e) {
```

**Code Example:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.woof_list_radio > [class^=woof_term_]', function(e) {
  let len = $(this).closest('.woof_term_224').length;
  if(len)
    console.log('The child');
  else
    console.log('Not the child');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

  <li class="woof_term_224">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent Category 1</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_224">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 1</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <br>

  <li class="woof_term_225">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">>Parent Category 2</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_225">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <br>

  <li class="woof_term_226">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">>Parent Category 3</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_226">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```

You can find the parent class of the clicked element in the following way:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.woof_list_radio > [class^=woof_term_]', function(e) {
  let parentClass = $(this).closest('[class^=woof_term_').prop('class');
  console.log('Element is the child of class',parentClass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

  <li class="woof_term_224">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent Category 1</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_224">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 1</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <br>

  <li class="woof_term_225">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">>Parent Category 2</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_225">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <br>

  <li class="woof_term_226">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">>Parent Category 3</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_226">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reponse. Can you update your code and make it not limited to woof_term_224  ?

Comment: @ConanCarroll, then which parent element you will be looking for?

Comment: Hmm.. By default when I click on a <label> element it will be added with a class or styled as bold

Comment: @ConanCarroll, though I am not quite sure of exact requirement, I have added another solution.....please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the target element (the element that was clicked) `.matches` the selector string for descendants of `.woof_term_224`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.woof_list_radio .woof_radio_label', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('.woof_term_224 *')) console.log('Clicked on child of 224')
  else console.log('Clicked on something outside of 224');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

  <li class="woof_term_224">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent Category 1</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_224">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 1</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <br>

  <li class="woof_term_225">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">>Parent Category 2</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_225">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <br>

  <li class="woof_term_226">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">>Parent Category 3</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_226">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label">Sub Category 3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your code make it flexible not just to class woof_term_224? like it was clicked outside its parent

Comment: I don't quite get it, the listener is listening for clicks on `.woof_radio_label`, and those elements will *necessarily* be children of their `woof_term_###` ancestors, right? Can you elaborate?